# Angular component's interface ( @Output / @Input ) how do you expose methods? Or certain type of events?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

In angular, we can encapsulate functionality in a component and define its interface via @Input and @Output

Interfaces in other systems typically include properties, methods and events.

It is clear how to make a property part of your interface - decorate it with @Input.
It's clear how to make an event part of your interface - decorate EventEmitter with @Output
It is not clear to me how to make a method part of your interface.
And also how to declare events where the event handlers can return a value.

Use cases:
My component is  a tree-table with buttons to delete add and edit rows. It has this:

```
 @Output() onDelete = new EventEmitter<TreeNode[]>();
```

this will notify the consumer that user wants to delete these nodes, but I want the consumer **to be able to cancel that delete (optionally)**. It would be easy to do if event handlers were allowed to return values. I would declare an event where handler takes in the same parameter (TreeNode[]) and returns a Boolean. But event handlers must return void as per definition of EventEmitter's emit(e: T):void

Yes I know you can wrap the object you want to pass to a component in another object and include some boolean property in that, but to me that seems like a hack. The interface becomes unclear.

Now the case for methods:
I have in my component a method:

```
confirmEdit(node TreeNode)
```

I want the consumer of my component to be able to call this method.
How do I expose it via @Input or @Output?

Yes I know that the consumer can actually reach into my component via say @ViewChild and call any method it has, but that seems like a violation of encapsulation principle.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do that, but if you absolutely need that functionality, you can pass anything in the output, including a reference to the child component or some sort of callback function that allows you to do something on the child component. I don't necessarily recommend doing that, but it can be done very easily.

Comment: Hi @Geo242, for why I want that, read my question after "Why do I need that?" :) In my opinion it's a pretty common thing to want, so I was hoping there would be a clear and obvious solution to that. What you suggest is a work around. Valid, but kinda seems like there should be something better. Also if you read in my question after "Similar problem happens with" you will see another oversight.

Comment: You are indeed missing something fundamental. The statements you are making, like : Angular `@Output` event handlers can not return anything" and "The problem is `@Input` can't be a function", are false. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish more clearly or create a stackblitz that shows the deficiency you claim exists.

Comment: @Geo242 Output can't return value is referring to EventEmmiter<T> definition of emit(value?: T): void. Input can't be a function is referring to Input being a decorator for a property (not a method). Is that clear enough?

Comment: Why would you ever expect the emit function to return a value? The emit function is essentially just a wrapper around the `next` function of a `Subject`. The consumer of the output receives the `T`, which can literally be anything, including another function you can then call from the consumer. And, your claim that the input property can't be a function is false, you can absolutely do this and it's commonly done in many libraries.

Comment: Depending on your actual code and app structure in this case, I think you should either create more Inputs/Outputs for specific user's actions (handling the cancelling separately), use Input as a callback function, or even consider changing the structure of the components and separation of concerns. This is, I know, mostly theoretical, but that's as far as I could go with a theoretical problem explanation. Stackblitz would do wonders here in understanding your issue better.

Comment: Using Input as call back is something I also noticed as a possibility and it kinda solves the problem of returning something from an event handler, but also seems like a non pattern. If events are supposed to be Output then calling almost the same thing @Input seems wrong. Is this a widespread pattern? As for the other issue (how do I expose a method?) I don't think it's all that confusing as a question. Methods are bread and butter of any interface. In go interfaces ONLY have methods. If Component's interface is supposed to be exposed via Input and Output then how do I expose a method?

Comment: Well, Input as callback function is there, and it's not a great option, but it's there :D For method exposure, and explicitly *not* using ViewChild because it breaks encapsulation, my concern is: do you think it is at all possible to imagine accessing child's methods without breaking the encapsulation? Thus I suggested restructuring of the code and separation of concerns: If child only acts as UI while parent handles the works, then just have emitters in child. If child does the work, no need for parent to access the methods, again just emit to parent when the work is done in child.